# Adding MKPolyLine NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mkmapview

I'm trying to add MKPolyLine to my mapView. But got error: `NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MKPolylineView boundingMapRect]`
My code:

```
- (void)addRoad {
    [self loadRoude];
    [self.mapView addOverlay:self.routeLine];
}

- (void)loadRoude{
    MKMapPoint northEastPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate);
MKMapPoint southWestPoint = MKMapPointMake(52.142391, 21.055641);

    MKMapPoint* pointArr = malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D) * 2);
    pointArr[0] = northEastPoint;
    pointArr[1] = southWestPoint;

    self.routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithPoints:pointArr count:2];
    _routeRect = MKMapRectMake(southWestPoint.x, southWestPoint.y, northEastPoint.x - southWestPoint.x, northEastPoint.y - southWestPoint.y);
    free(pointArr);
}

- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
MKOverlayView* overlayView = nil;

if(overlay == self.routeLine)
{
        if(nil == self.routeLineView)
    {
        self.routeLineView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:self.routeLine];
        self.routeLineView.fillColor = [UIColor redColor];
        self.routeLineView.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
        self.routeLineView.lineWidth = 3;
    }
    overlayView = self.routeLineView;
}
return overlayView; 
}
```

There is my problem?

**EDIT**

NSLog of self.routeLineView shows me : `outeLiveView = <MKPolylineView: 0x7c956d0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); opaque = NO; layer = <MKOverlayClusterProxyLayer: 0x7c97eb0>>` Is this normal?

**EDIT2**

```
NSLog(@"pointArr[0]x = %f",pointArr[0].x);
NSLog(@"pointArr[0]y = %f",pointArr[0].y);
NSLog(@"pointArr[1]x = %f",pointArr[1].x);
NSLog(@"pointArr[1]y = %f",pointArr[1].y);
```

show:

```
pointArr[0]x = 149891376.014222
pointArr[0]y = 88510604.996837
pointArr[1]x = 149917951.870020
pointArr[1]y = 88495551.883086
```

That mean my pointers array have no nil objects. I'm really in shock

Comment: `MKMapPointMake(52.142391, 21.055641)` should be `MKMapPointForCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.142391, 21.055641))` (because an MKMapPoint is not the same as a lat/long coordinate) but that should not cause the exception you see.

Comment: @AnnaKarenina yeap, rewrote, but still have same error

Comment: @AnnaKarenina added nslog of view

Comment: Does it say "unrecognized selector" after the error?  `boundingMapRect` is a property of the overlay (MKPolyline) and not the overlay view (MKPolylineView).  How is the routeLineView property declared and what other code uses it?

Comment: @AnnaKarenina yes, `boundingMapRect]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7d55ff0'`. `routeLineView` declared in `loadView` as `self.routeLineView = nil;`. All code which uses `routeLineView` I wrote above.

Comment: The NSLog of pointArr is not relevant.  Based on the exception, it sounds like the routeLine overlay variable is losing its reference to the overlay.  Later the map view tries to get the overlay's boundingMapRect and can't.  Are you adding more than one road at a time and thus losing reference to the previous road segment?

Comment: @AnnaKarenina no, at that time I trying to add only one road..

Answer (score 0):

From Apple's documentation:

> NSInvalidArgumentException: Name of an exception that occurs when you
>   pass an invalid argument to a method, such as a nil pointer where a
>   non-nil object is required. Available in Mac OS X v10.0 and later.

Check the values you are using to initialize `routeLineView` or any other `MKPolylineView` objects. One is probably `nil`.

Comment: But if one of the values you initialize it with is `nil` you'd get that error.